# How to draw a dashed line?

Tags: c++, sdl

I need to draw a dashed line(for pong) using SDL.
I want to do it in a for loop because making and rendering 10 different rectangles costs too many lines of code.
So just for clearness, not this:

```
SDL_Rect pieceOfLine = {x,y,w,h};
SDL_Rect pieceOfLine1 = {x,y,w,h};
SDL_Rect pieceOfLine2 = {x,y,w,h};
```

etc.

But sort of this(I tried this but it didn't work):

```
SDL_Rect line = {x,y,w,h};
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,&line);
    line.y += 30; //So actually a line with holes in it
}
```

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.
This is an example of what I actually need(In my program):

|

|

|

|

|

|

Comment: "using a for loop" - what? That's like "how can I build a house using my limbs"

Comment: I used a for loop to draw a dashed line in Pygame(Python), but the SDL drawing system works different. That is why I need help :(

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't sufficiently clear...what happened? how does it look different? Did you see if there is an [error code returned](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderFillRect)?

Comment: The code compiled without errors but, I was only seeing the line rect going down the screen, because of line.y += 30;
But I don't know how to draw multiple lines under each other(Actually a dashed line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks pretty good, but you need to make `h` equal to 15, otherwise you're just drawing ten lines on top of each other, slightly offset.